# Code after await for is not running flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to call a function which will populate a list by reading a stream. Means, it will read a stream and add values to a list and finally, the list will be returned by the function.

The problem is, when I'm using await for to read the stream, the code after the await for is not getting executed. And I tried to use listen, then it's not waiting to finish reading the stream. The code after the listen is getting executed even before the stream is read completely.

Following in my code -

```
Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> getNearestDriver(Stream<List<DocumentSnapshot>> driverWithinRangeStream, GeoPoint source) async {
    print("Get Nearest Driver Called");
    List<Map<String, dynamic>> driverAvailableList = [];
    await for (List<DocumentSnapshot> documentList in driverWithinRangeStream){
      documentList.forEach((DocumentSnapshot document) async {
        String driverIDVar = document.data['driverid'];
        GeoPoint pos = document.data['position']['geopoint'];
        var point = geo.point(latitude: pos.latitude, longitude: pos.longitude);
        double distanceVar = point.distance(lat: source.latitude, lng: source.longitude);
        int distanceInMeter = (distanceVar*1000).round();
        Map<String, dynamic> newDriverAvailable = {"driverId": driverIDVar, "distance" : distanceInMeter};
        driverAvailableList.add(newDriverAvailable);
      });
      print(driverAvailableList); /* <- I get the data here */
    }
    print(driverAvailableList); /* <- But I don't get the data here. This code is not even being executed. */
  }
```

Please let me know what's wrong here.

Answer (score 1):

Would you mind to try

```
try{
    await for (List<DocumentSnapshot> documentList in driverWithinRangeStream){
        await Future.forEach(documentList, (DocumentSnapshot document) async {
           try{     
                String driverIDVar = document.data['driverid'];
                GeoPoint pos = document.data['position']['geopoint'];
                var point = geo.point(latitude: pos.latitude, longitude: pos.longitude);
                double distanceVar = point.distance(lat: source.latitude, lng: source.longitude);
                int distanceInMeter = (distanceVar*1000).round();
                Map<String, dynamic> newDriverAvailable = {"driverId": driverIDVar, "distance" : distanceInMeter};
                driverAvailableList.add(newDriverAvailable);
           }catch(error){
                throw "throw from documentList, Error:$error";}
        });
    }
 }catch(error){
     print ("catch in driverWithinRangeStream, Error:$error");}
```

Comment: Hi Sam, in this case where it'll get the documentList from? This code will be withing the await for only..right?

Comment: yes, it should replace `documentList.forEach((DocumentSnapshot document) async {`

Comment: Tried this. But same result. Somehow the await for is not finishing and the code after that is not reading.

Comment: @Alias could you add `try()catch` to see if the which part get error. It still not sure that which list looping case error. May be one of list get `null` and throw error. I edit my answer